# Existence of perfect matching after swapping colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, matching-theory

I am thinking about a problem for quite a while now and I can't seem to find some way to tackle it or to find relevant info regarding known results. The problem I'm interested in is as follows. Suppose we have a graph $G(V,E)$ and a function $f$, which maps every edge to another edge. For example edge 1 gets mapped onto edge 3, edge 2 onto edge 4, ..., it can be any kind of mapping. Now we consider an edge coloring on the graph $C_1$. We now swap the colors of the edges according to the function $f$ to get a new coloring $C_2$. In the example edge 3 gets the color of edge 1, edge 4 gets the color of edge 2 and so on. The question I'm now interested in is:

Does there exist a coloring $C_1$ that contains a perfect matching on the graph $G$, such that after the swapping, the coloring $C_2$ also contains a perfect matching on the graph $G$?

What properties does $f$ need to have to satisfy this property?

I know this is a very general question and I have no clue how to tackle it. I do not know if this question is even interesting. Any sort of help or insight is appreciated even if it's a only very specific case.

I'm actually mostly interested in the case of bipartite graphs and 2-color colorings, but any other variation is surely welcome.

Comment: What does it mean to say that an edge coloring contains a perfect matching?   I also don't understand the role of the function.  It seems like we can just change the edge colors arbitrarily.

Comment: As I understand a perfect matching is a set of edges with the same color, such that every vertex is incident to an edge in the matching and no two edges in the matching share a vertex. The role of the function is to set the rules of the swapping. I imagine it as swapping edges of the graph after coloring them. For example we color a graph and then swap the first two edges their color. In this case f would map edge 1 onto edge 2 andall the other edges onto themselves.

Comment: Thought I understood, but I'm still not sure.  First you ask a question, "Does there exist a perfect matching ...", and then you ask "What properties does $f$ need to have to satisfy this property?"  I'm not sure what "this property" is.  Is that whenever $C_1$ contains a perfect matching then so does $C_2$?

Comment: Sorry for the bad phrasing, but what I mean with "this property" is that a given $f$ has "this property" if: there exists a $C_1$ that contains a perfect matching, such that $C_2$ constructed with this $f$ also contains a perfect matching.